# Как правильно записать в файл массив в формате json из базы данных php

Tags: php, mysql, json

В базе данных находится массив в формате json, получаю его запросом для того чтобы в дальнейшем записать его в файл, а после перебирать его и вытаскивать из него данные. Проблема в том что в файл записывается вот такой результат:
[{"data":"{\"id\":17,\"name\":\"John Doe\"}"}] , а мне нужно чтобы он записался  в таком виде [{"data":{"id":17,"name":"John Doe"}}](нужно избавится от этих знаков '\'), иначе я не смогу манипулировать с данными которые являются значениями ключа data. Если пытаюсь декодить и вытаскивать их выдаёт ошибку.

Как мне прийти к второму нужному варианту? В чем я ошибаюсь?

Вот код которым я получаю данные и записываю в файл

```
Модель
  public function getNotifyData() {
       $data_notify = DB::table('notifications')
       ->select('data')->get();
       return $data_notify;
    }

Контроллер

  protected $follower;
    public function __construct() {
       $this->info_users = new InfoUsers;
       $this->follower = new Follower;
    }

    public function notifications() {
$get_notify = $this->follower->getNotifyData();
     $file = "data.json";
  $data_file = file_put_contents($file,$get_notify);

}
```

Таблица из базы, в столбце data содержатся нужные мне данные
[image: База данных]
результат выполнения кода

[{"data":"{\"id\":17,\"name\":\"John Doe\"}"}]

Comment: если вам не обязательно в базе хранить данные с слешами можно перед сохранением в функции json_encode 2м аргументом указать 64. Не нужно будет в итоге пользоваться таким тяжеловесом как регулярка, так как по факту этих слешей изначально не будет)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$string = '[{"data":"{\"id\":17,\"name\":\"John Doe\"}"}]';
$pattern = '/\\\\/i';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```